# What is a "good stop gap"?

Tags: vocabulary

Sentence:

> *A* is a good stop gap before I find a better place to get help.

Does it mean that *A* is good but temporary?

Comment: It means that it is a good temporary solution.

Comment: It means a finger in the dike.

Comment: I'm guessing there is confusion over the parsing. *[Stopgap](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/american_english/stopgap)* and *stop-gap* are much more common these days than *stop gap*, though the closed compound is much more popular in American English.

Comment: US$1 million (UK£ 666K)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A stopgap (or stop-gap) measure is an action which is taken to fulfill an important function temporarily. Commenter @HotLicks gave a good analogy or metaphor with his "finger in the dike."

There is the legend of a young Dutch boy who stuck his finger in a hole in the dike (or dam) where water was leaking through the dike. His finger, then, served as a *stop-gap measure* until someone could come along and effect a more permanent repair.

There is another common saying:

> "A stitch in time saves nine."

In other words, if you stitch (or sew) a small rip or tear in a piece of fabric when it is small, you might just prevent a larger rip which will require more (viz., nine) stitches.

Synonymous expressions for stop-gap:

> - temporary fix
> - an important but temporary segue
> - good for the time being
> - an adequate solution for now
> - an in-between measure
> - an interim solution
> - It'll do, for now

Answer (score 1):

> A **stopgap** is a temporary solution to a problem, like **a piece of
>   cardboard taped over the broken window in your car**. Until you can get
>   it fixed, you need a stopgap.

[Stop·gap](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/stopgap) (n): 
An **improvised** substitute for something lacking; a temporary expedient. (TFD)

***Calling a stopgap arrangement *good* would depend upon what you consider as a *better* arrangement/solution.***